# Floor-plan in Android and svg

Tags: javascript, android, html, svg, android-canvas

I want to show a simple custom floor-plan in my Android app, something similar to the image below:

[image: image1]

The target is to colour the area where I am currently in (I get this info in my app):

[image: image2]

It would be perfect if each of these areas are also clickable to set an onclicklistener or similar and be able to zoom in/out as with images.

The main restriction is I want everything local, that is, no connection to an internet service to import the image.

I have tried loading an html which contains an svg floor-plan, but I don't know how to change the colour of an area from Android when I move from one area to another.

How can I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple html page within a WebView and attach the SVG and add Javascript, so when tapping on the some elements in the svg to call a javascript function. You can then sent the events to the native java code in your android app if your app is native or just handle it in the html.

I believe this article is especially for your question [Interfacing with SVG](http://tumba.solutions/blog/svg)

Comment: Can you please check this [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N25MxHZ9dDE) and give me clue or guide me or help me to find tutorials. I'm trying to place some objects on real world coordinates through Android camera when I click.

Answer (score 0):

you'r floor looks a lot like a grid layout!! why are you doing so much work to achieve something very simple? what you need to do is dynamically create a grid layout then put other views in it

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that way I won't be able to zoom because each view will be zoomed separately instead of zooming as a whole image, will I?

Comment: in any case your implementing zooming behavior youself so implement it is a way when some gusture happens whole view get zoomed in / out. remember if u return false in onTouch method u can send touch event to the parent view which is grid layout. i don't know exact detail on how to implement zooming but i don't see any conflict with zooming and grid layout. maybe i'm not completly understand your problem

Comment: Can you please check this [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N25MxHZ9dDE) and give me clue or guide me or help me to find tutorials. I'm trying to place some objects on real world coordinates through Android camera when I click.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very open-ended question.  It's also not simple.

You're going to have to do a lot of low-level coding to achieve what you outlined.  No matter the case, you're going to have to find a way to turn that SVG into something that can be interacted with.  The limiting factor here is that you're using SVGs--that's not a data format, it's vector.  Unless you parse SVG into something more usable for a UI, or can get this data in a different format (some form of parsed JSON?), you're just showing an image.

Now assuming you do find a way to get this data more accessibly, you could go down the path of a custom view and overriding the draw().  Then you could just draw out your rooms and positions where you want, add a TouchListener, add a drawing state machine, etc.  Alternatively to the View.draw(), you could use an GLSurfaceView and draw with hardware language.

Comment: Hello Gregory. I am not restricted to SVG, so if you have a simpler alternative that could do the work I will be happy to try it :)

Comment: You should read this: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html  Make your own view that you set a data set to, then manipulate that dataset to do the drawing.  It'll become more complicated if you need to have pinching, but with custom drawing you can at least set out each thing and render them.  I'd use a basic OnTouchListener, pass the x,y through your object set to determine which Rect it is touching, and then handle it.

Comment: What's wrong with SVG? I attach OnClick ot my `path`s in SVG, for instance - Google for more, but here is nothing problematic with SVGs; paths can be interacted with